# Transpose transactional data in SQL and group by User ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, sql-server-2017

I wanted to transpose a Table that contains User Transactions that shows the history of purchases for each user. The current dataset is designed as followed:

```
USER ID |   Transaction #  |   PRODUCT NAME |    Amount £
   1               1             Free Pass          0.00   
   1               2             Monthly Pass      10.00        
   1               3             Monthly Pass      10.00        
   2               1             Free pass          0.00   
   2               2             Year Pass        100.00
   3               1             Basic pass         5.00
```

However, I would like to transpose the data in order to display a single row per User ID and have each transaction listed horizontally. The end result in SQL that I was hoping for is:

```
USER ID |   Transaction 1 | Amount 1 |  Transaction 2 | Amount 2 |  Transaction 3 | Amount 3 | 
   1          Free Pass      0.00        Monthly Pass     10.00      Monthly Pass    10.00          
   2          Free Pass      0.00        Year Pass       100.00     
   3          Basic Pass     5.00
```

Comment: Don't post images of text, post text instead. The second image is to small to be read on my display for instance and images can't be converted to `INSERT INTO...` when testing a solution.

Comment: i have managed to fix the data in the question

Comment: Great! Now that I see it's a dynamic pivot I need to ask you what DBMS you're using?

Comment: I am using SSMS 17

Answer (score 0):

You can use `conditional aggregation` as

```
    with tab(USERID, Transaction#, PRODUCTNAME, Amount) as
    (
     select 1,1,'Free Pass'   ,  0 union all   
     select 1,2,'Monthly Pass', 10 union all       
     select 1,3,'Monthly Pass', 10 union all       
     select 2,1,'Free pass'   ,  0 union all   
     select 2,2,'Year Pass'   ,100 union all
     select 3,1,'Basic pass'  ,  5 
    )
    select [USERID],
           max(case when Transaction# = 1 then Productname end)
           as 'Transaction 1',
           max(case when Transaction# = 1 then Amount end)
           as 'Amount 1',
           max(case when Transaction# = 2 then Productname end)
           as 'Transaction 2',
           max(case when Transaction# = 2 then Amount end)
           as 'Amount 2',
           max(case when Transaction# = 3 then Productname end)
           as 'Transaction 3',
           max(case when Transaction# = 3 then Amount end)
           as 'Amount 3'               
      from tab t
     group by [USERID]
```

<kbd>[Rextester Demo](https://rextester.com/HPATW90551)</kbd>

Comment: And when there is a transaction #4?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson do you mean making it dynamic ..? Unfortunately, In any case(even if you use pivot keyword) need to add new components explicitly

Comment: yes, there will be transactions upto 20 per User ID, it will need to be dyanmic